# Delphi Firemonkey Android TEdit swipe to scroll not to focus

Tags: scroll, focus, screen, edit

I noticed when I'm trying to scroll screen over TEdit then the Virtual Keyboard is triggered. How to make the TEdit only focused once TEdit really tapped?. I tried other application in play store and it can be done, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a work-a-round. I cycle through all the controls on a form and:

- Set the CanFocus property to FALSE.
- Assign OnClick which sets the CanFocus to TRUE and calls SetFocus for the Sender.
- Assign OnTap which does the same.
- Assign OnExit which sets the CanFocus property to FALSE.